# Filtering the value using java 8 map

Tags: java, filter, java-stream

I am working of CSV file reader . Need to replace first and last  word of 12345,sdc,CAP,12345:sdc-posistion-svc:SnakeYAML:2.1:3 (12345 and 3) from above lines an replace ": with ","

Sample CSV file

```
col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6,col7,col8
CVM Finding,12345,sdc,CAP,12345:sdc-posistion-svc:SnakeYAML:2.1:3,TRUE,FALSE,OverDue
CVM Finding,12345,sdc,CAP,12345:sdc-event-generation-svc:SpringBoot:2.1.2.Release:1,TRUE,FALSE,Overdue
CVM Finding,12345,sdc,CAP,12345:sdc-event-subscription-svc:Apache Tomcat:9.0.70:1,TRUE,FALSE,Due in <= 90
CVM Finding,12345,sdc,CAP,12345:sdc-bh-registry-svc:Jettison - Json Stax implementation:1.5.3:1,TRUE,FALSE,Due in <=90
CVM Finding,12345,sdc,CAP,12345:sdc-event-generation-svc:Apache Tomcat:9.0.70:2,TRUE,FALSE,Due in >90
CVM Finding,12345,sdc,CAP,12345:sdc-posistion-svc:jackson-databind:2.14:1,TRUE,FALSE,OverDue
CVM Finding,12345,sdc,CAP,12345:sdc-event-subscription-svc:jackson-databind:2.14:1,TRUE,FALSE,Due in <= 90
CVM Finding,12345,sdc,CAP,12345:sdc-event-subscription-svc:SpringBoot:2.1.2.Release:1,TRUE,FALSE,Overdue
CVM Finding,12345,sdc,CAP,12345:sdc-posistion-svc:SpringBoot:2.1.2.Release:1,TRUE,FALSE,OverDue
```

With below code

```
public static void getData3() throws IOException 
    {
        MyClass myClass = new MyClass(5, 7);
        String titleForCol5 = "col5";
        String titleForCol8 = "col8";
        
        Path path = Paths.get("D:/blackduck_sample.txt");

        if (Files.exists(path)) {
            List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(path);

            List<String> columns = Arrays.asList(lines.get(0).split(","));

            int col5Idex = columns.indexOf(titleForCol5);
            int col8Idex = columns.indexOf(titleForCol8);

            List<String> values2 = lines.stream().skip(1).map(line -> Arrays.asList(line.split(",")))
                    .map(list -> list.get(col5Idex).concat(",").concat(list.get(col8Idex))).filter(Objects::nonNull).filter(s -> s.trim().length() > 0)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
            
            values2.forEach(System.out::println);
        }
        
    }
```

I am getting

```
12345:sdc-posistion-svc:SnakeYAML:2.1:3,OverDue
12345:sdc-event-generation-svc:SpringBoot:2.1.2.Release:1,Overdue
12345:sdc-event-subscription-svc:Apache Tomcat:9.0.70:1,Due in <= 90
```

I want to change each line from the above output like the one below.

remove the first and last word of the first field and replace ":" with ",".

```
sdc-posistion-svc,SnakeYAML,2.1,OverDue
sdc-event-generation-svc,SpringBoot,2.1.2.Release,Overdue
sdc-event-subscription-svc,Apache Tomcat,9.0.70,Due in <= 90
```

Is it possible to do this on the same map?

I tried without java 6 map as below

```
List<String> lines =  Files.readAllLines(file.toPath(),StandardCharsets.UTF_8); 
              for (String line : lines) {
              String[] array = line.split(",");
              String tempStr =  array[4].replaceAll(":", ",") ;
              System.out.println(tempStr); 
              String shortened = tempStr.substring(0, tempStr.lastIndexOf(',', tempStr.length() - 2));            
              String shortened1 = shortened.replaceFirst("\\b\\w+\\b","").substring(1)+","+array[7];
              
              System.out.println(shortened1); //
              System.out.println(lst.add(array[4].replaceAll(":", ","))); }
```

I want to do it better way using map

Comment: Have you considered just using a CSV parser?

Comment: As far as I have understood, I do not see any use case of using a Maps to find and replace characters in a String. Using basic string or regex operations should suffice, as you done above. Let me know if I missed something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add a method and and then use it in `map`, that way you can add more features in future + your `stream` does not look too complicated:

```java
private static String postProcess(String line) {
        String[] array = line.split(",");
        String tempStr =  array[0].replaceAll(":", ",") ;
        return tempStr.substring(0,
                tempStr.lastIndexOf(',', tempStr.length() - 2))
                .replaceFirst("\\b\\w+\\b","")
                .substring(1) + "," + array[1];
    }
```

Then use it like:

```java
List<String> values2 = lines.stream().skip(1).map(line -> Arrays.asList(line.split(",")))
                    .map(list -> list.get(col5Idex).concat(",").concat(list.get(col8Idex)))
                    .filter(s -> s.trim().length() > 0)
                    .map(ClassName::postProcess)
                    .toList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. But, I would prefer readability over conciseness. The way you have done yourself is not a bad approach at all and it is readily understandable.

Although, it can be done on the same map as well.

```
.map(list -> list.get(titleIndex).replace(":",",").
             substring(list.get(titleIndex).indexOf(":") +1 , list.get(titleIndex).lastIndexOf(":")).
             concat(",").concat(list.get(col8Idex)))
```

But, please note that readable code is always better than concise but difficult to read code.

Answer (score 1):

> *"... I want to change each line from the above output like the one below.*
>
> *remove the first and last word of the first field and replace ":" with ",". ..."*

One way is to use the *[String#split](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String,int))* method with a limit of 3.
This will assure that the last element contains the `:` that should be replaced.

You can then use the *[String#join](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#join(java.lang.CharSequence,java.lang.CharSequence...))* method to return the arrays to *String* values.

```java
List<String> list = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("files/data.csv"));
String[] strings, substrings;
int index = 0;
for (String string : list) {
    strings = string.split(",", -1);
    substrings = strings[4].split(":", 3);
    substrings[substrings.length - 1] = substrings[substrings.length - 1].replace(":", ",");
    strings[4] = String.join(":", substrings);
    list.set(index++, String.join(",", strings));
}
```

Output

```
col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6,col7,col8
CVM Finding,12345,sdc,CAP,12345:sdc-posistion-svc:SnakeYAML,2.1,3,TRUE,FALSE,OverDue
CVM Finding,12345,sdc,CAP,12345:sdc-event-generation-svc:SpringBoot,2.1.2.Release,1,TRUE,FALSE,Overdue
CVM Finding,12345,sdc,CAP,12345:sdc-event-subscription-svc:Apache Tomcat,9.0.70,1,TRUE,FALSE,Due in <= 90
CVM Finding,12345,sdc,CAP,12345:sdc-bh-registry-svc:Jettison - Json Stax implementation,1.5.3,1,TRUE,FALSE,Due in <=90
CVM Finding,12345,sdc,CAP,12345:sdc-event-generation-svc:Apache Tomcat,9.0.70,2,TRUE,FALSE,Due in >90
CVM Finding,12345,sdc,CAP,12345:sdc-posistion-svc:jackson-databind,2.14,1,TRUE,FALSE,OverDue
CVM Finding,12345,sdc,CAP,12345:sdc-event-subscription-svc:jackson-databind,2.14,1,TRUE,FALSE,Due in <= 90
CVM Finding,12345,sdc,CAP,12345:sdc-event-subscription-svc:SpringBoot,2.1.2.Release,1,TRUE,FALSE,Overdue
CVM Finding,12345,sdc,CAP,12345:sdc-posistion-svc:SpringBoot,2.1.2.Release,1,TRUE,FALSE,OverDue
```

> *"... Is it possible to do this on the same map? ..."*

Yes, here is an example.
Note that you will need to use local variables within the closure, so this is obviously not as optimal.

```java
List<String> list
  = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("files/data.csv"))
         .stream().map(line -> {
             String[] strings = line.split(",", -1);
             String[] substrings = strings[4].split(":", 3);
             substrings[substrings.length - 1] = substrings[substrings.length - 1].replace(":", ",");
             strings[4] = String.join(":", substrings);
             return String.join(",", strings);
         }).toList();
```

Comment: Thank you all. I used @PatioFurnitureIsCool's suggestions. But others like Hermit and Reilas answers help to gain knowledge.